# Starting an AWS Instance with API, AUTHPARAMS

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am trying to start an AMI using

```
https://ec2.amazonaws.com/
?Action=StartInstances
&InstanceId.1=i-10a64379
&AUTHPARAMS
```

Like documentadion says [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/starting-stopping-instances.html) but I am unable to find what AUTHPARAMS refers to.
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

As Steffen notes, the API is much easier to use than the direct REST calls (especially the reasonably new [Command Line Interface](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) -- which is much more lightweight, and arguably easier to use as a result of the JSON integration, than the original by-product Command Line Tools)

...but if you are determined:

It's somewhat buried in the documentation, but the following links seem to lead us toward an answer:

1) the [high level description](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/CommonParameters.html) of the "AUTHPARAMS" (as referenced frequently in the API documentation.)

> **AuthParams**
>
> The parameters that are required to authenticate a
>   Conditional request. Contains:
>
> > AWSAccessKeyID
> >
> > SignatureVersion
> >
> > Timestamp
> >
> > Signature
>
> Default: None
>
> Required: Conditional

2) a [step by step outline](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/rest-signature.html) of the parameters needed for a REST request:

3) the [detailed outline](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html) of the method to derive the **"signature"** for the "AUTHPARAMS"

This is the example in the documentation (I've added newlines to make it easier to read)

```
https://elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com?
AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE&
Action=DescribeJobFlows&
SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&
SignatureVersion=2&
Timestamp=2011-10-03T15%3A19%3A30&
Version=2009-03-31&
Signature=i91nKc4PWAt0JJIdXwz9HxZCJDdiy6cf%2FMj6vPxyYIs%3D
```

4) Additionally there is [some general information here about signatures](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html)

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, to interact with the [Amazon EC2 API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html), I highly recommend to use one of the available [SDKs](http://aws.amazon.com/tools/) if possible - this will make your life much simpler, especially when also interacting with any of the many other [AWS Products and Solutions](http://aws.amazon.com/products-solutions/) over time, insofar the SDKs relief you from tedious boilerplate code and also harmonize cross services API usage in general and the authentication process you are asking about in particular.

Now, if you really want/need to handle authentication yourself, you'll find the required information in [Query API Authentication](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-query-api.html), which links to [Signature Version 2 Signing Process](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html) in turn (the signature version changes over time, which is one of the topics the SDKs abstract away for example).